# Lag difference within multiple groups not working correctly

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that contains quarterly accumulated values for several categories, and I want to extract the quarterly value (i.e. no calculation for the first quarter of the year, and the difference of quarterly values for others quarters of the year). Not sure if this matters, but my real dataset has several data points missing.

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
x <- tibble(periode = (rep(c(as_date("2019-12-31"),as_date("2020-12-31"),as_date("2021-12-31")),4)), 
    grp =as_factor(c(rep("V1",6), rep("V2",6))), 
    cat = as_factor(c(rep("a",3), rep("b",3),rep("a",3), rep("b",3))), 
    valeur = c(1, 1.5, 0.5, 2, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 5, 7, 6, 10, 11))
```

I would like to have for each groups (i.e. both 'grp' and 'cat' variables) the difference of 'valeur' variable between 2 dates. Expected result would be:

| Periode | grp | cat | valeur | val_lag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-12-31 | V1 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2019-12-31 | V1 | b | 2 | 2 |
| 2019-12-31 | V2 | a | 6.5 | 6.5 |
| 2019-12-31 | V2 | b | 6 | 6 |
| 2020-12-31 | V1 | a | 1.5 | 0.5 |
| 2020-12-31 | V1 | b | 5.5 | 3.5 |
| 2020-12-31 | V2 | a | 5 | -1.5 |
| 2020-12-31 | V2 | b | 10 | 4 |
| 2021-12-31 | V1 | a | 0.5 | -1 |
| 2021-12-31 | V1 | b | 6 | 0.5 |
| 2021-12-31 | V2 | a | 7 | 2 |
| 2021-12-31 | V2 | b | 11 | 1 |

This is the code I tried, but I'm not getting the lag by groups, only by the previous line. Not sure why it is not working, as it looks like the code I saw on others answers.

```
x %>% group_by(periode,grp, cat) %>% 
      arrange(periode) %>% 
      mutate(val_lag = valeur - lag(valeur, order_by = periode))
```

Any suggestions using the *tidyverse* packages would be greatly appreciated.

Using the following code with the data.table package is working correctly :

```
setDT(x)
x[,.(periode, grp, cat, valeur, val_lag=valeur- shift(valeur, type="lag") ), by=.(cat, grp)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't want any calculation done for the first value. lag(x) returns NA if it's the first row of x. You can give it the default value of 0, and that way, the first calculation will subtract 0 and give the first value for each group untouched!

```
library(dplyr)

x |>
  mutate(val_lag = valeur - lag(valeur, default = 0), .by = c(grp, cat)) |>
  arrange(periode, grp, cat)
```

Output:

```
   periode    grp   cat   valeur val_lag
   <date>     <fct> <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2019-12-31 V1    a        1       1  
 2 2019-12-31 V1    b        2       2  
 3 2019-12-31 V2    a        6.5     6.5
 4 2019-12-31 V2    b        6       6  
 5 2020-12-31 V1    a        1.5     0.5
 6 2020-12-31 V1    b        5.5     3.5
 7 2020-12-31 V2    a        5      -1.5
 8 2020-12-31 V2    b       10       4  
 9 2021-12-31 V1    a        0.5    -1  
10 2021-12-31 V1    b        6       0.5
11 2021-12-31 V2    a        7       2  
12 2021-12-31 V2    b       11       1
```

Comment: I have the following error when typing 
`x %>%  mutate(val_lag = ifelse(is.na(lag(valeur)), valeur, valeur - lag(valeur)), .by = c(grp, cat)) %>%
  arrange(periode, grp, cat)` : 
*Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 24 rows, data has 12*

Comment: try `tibble(periode = (rep(c(as_date("2019-12-31"),as_date("2020-12-31"),as_date("2021-12-31")),4)), 
    grp =as_factor(c(rep("V1",6), rep("V2",6))), 
    cat = as_factor(c(rep("a",3), rep("b",3),rep("a",3), rep("b",3))), 
    valeur = c(1, 1.5, 0.5, 2, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 5, 7, 6, 10, 11)) |>
  mutate(val_lag = valeur - lag(valeur, default = 0), .by = c(grp, cat)) |>
  arrange(periode, grp, cat)`

Comment: Same error than before. Do I understand correctly that your `|>` is a pipe ie `%>%` ?
I added `dplyr::` to make sure I did use the correct package for the function.
Btw, I never used the `.by=` before, very useful to know, thanks.

Comment: okay, in that case, if you literally ran the code in my comment verbatim, without changing anything whatsoever, there is something wrong with your install, because I ran the code and it worked fine

Comment: wait did you load the libraries? library(dplyr) library(tibble) ?!?

Comment: You were right about the libraries. Somehow, after updating the dplyr package to 1.1.2, it works. Apology for the confusion, not sure why it was not working before, but thanks for letting me understand the issue !

Comment: how odd! I think maybe it could be to do with .by, but that's only a guess. Glad it worked in the end